# Selenium Webdriver run as administrator

Tags: selenium, automated-tests

I have developed a tool using Selenium webdriver. I am using the Chrome driver. I was wondering if its possible to run the Chrome browser that launches as administrator.

I cannot log in to the machine using the administrator account, but the administrator has allowed the use of 'Run as Administrator' without putting in the admin credentials. I am not technically sure how this is set up in the company.

The requirement that I'm doing needs to have the browser running as administrator.

Is this set up using `System.setProperty` or something else?

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
```